# Heroku thinks everything is up to date when it is not

Tags: git, heroku

I recently did:

```
git push -f heroku master
```

Now when I try to push new changes to heroku, it says "Everything is up to date". Maybe forcing the last git push doesn't have anything to do with the problem, but I'm new to Heroku and Git and I'm completely lost.

Also, I am working on the "master" branch:

```
git branch
* master
```

Don't even know what to try. Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT:

Maybe this helps: When I push to Github, it also returns "Everything up-to-date". But the difference is that Github actually has the latest code. Heroku, on the other hand, doesn't have the latest code. I'm sure about this cause I can easily compare a css file that is hosted on an Amazon Bucket (heroku), a css file on Github and a css file on my local env. Github and my local env are identical while the css file on github doesn't reflect the changes.
... Could it be a problem with collectstatic?.

UPDATE:

It is a problem with collectstatic, I haven't solved it yet. So, if anyone has a similar situation, consider double-checking your amazon AWS S3 - Django config. GL.

Comment: What a `git status` returns? May be it says "everything is up to date" because, well, everything is actually up to date (pushed to heroku)?

Comment: git status returns ´nothing to commit, working directory clean´. And when I try tu push to commit to heroku it reads "everything up to date". I did an update to the question trying to explain the situation better.

Comment: So... I'm allmost sure that all the things that are not "up-to-date" are contained in the staticfiles. So it is a problem with the staticfiles.

Comment: It seems to be an issue with how heroku updates its app, meaning the bare repo itself is up-to-date, but the files haven't be updated in the heroku-managed app space.

Comment: In fact, it was a problem with collectstatic. I haven't solved it yet, but becouse of the urgency I uploaded the files manualy to AWS S3.